# SQL procedure to show how many hours has worker worked

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
+-----------+-------------------------------+-------+
| Worker ID | Time(MM/DD/YYYY Hour:Min:Sec) | InOut |
+-----------+-------------------------------+-------+
|        1  |  12/04/2017 10:00:00          | In    |
|        2  |  12/04/2017 10:00:00          | In    |
|        2  |  12/04/2017 18:40:02          | Out   |
|        3  |  12/04/2017 10:00:00          | In    |
|        1  |  12/04/2017 12:01:00          | Out   |
|        3  |  12/04/2017 19:40:05          | Out   |
+-----------+-------------------------------+-------+
```

Hi! I have problem with my project and I thought some of you would help me. I have table like that. It is simple table that indicates worker getting in and out of company. I need to do procedure which would take ID and number of day as In parameters and it would show how many hours and minutes that worker has worked that day. Thanks for help.

Comment: You probably want to split Time into two columns, `Date`, and `Time`. Then `GROUP BY` `Worker ID` and `Date`, then calculate `(SUM(Time) WHERE InOut = IN) - (SUM(Time) WHERE InOut = "Out")`

Comment: @Mako - noooooo.  Please don't ever do that.  If I'm having to do date operations with SQL data, I *definitely* don't want to have to assemble two separate components together before performing the operation.  If the date is a single column, I can just call DATEDIFF; if the date is two columns, I have to call DATEDIFF twice, and then add the values together.  Heck, there's isn't even a good way of telling whether one row is earlier/later than another row if date and time are split into separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had to do a number of queries like this at my old job.  Here's the approach I used, and it worked out pretty well:

For each "Out" record, get the MAX(TIME) on "In" records with a time *earlier* than the OUT record

Does that make sense?  You're basically joining the table against itself, looking for the record that represents the "clock in" time for any particular "clock out" time.

So here's the backbone:

```
select
*
, (
        SELECT MAX(tim) from @tempTable subQ
        where subQ.id = main.id
        and subQ.tim <= main.tim
        and subQ.InOut = 'In'
  ) as correspondingInTime
from @tempTable main
where InOut = 'Out'
```

... from here, you can get the data you need.  Either by manipulating the query above, or using it as a subquery itself (which is my favored way of doing it) - something like:

```
select id as workerID, sum(DATEDIFF(s, correspondingInTime, tim)) as totalSecondsWorked
from
(
    select
    *
    , (
            SELECT MAX(tim) from @tempTable subQ
            where subQ.id = main.id
            and subQ.tim <= main.tim
            and subQ.InOut = 'In'
      ) correspondingInTime
    from @tempTable main
    where InOut = 'Out'
) mainQuery
group by id
```

EDIT: Remove the 'as' before correspondingInTime, because oracle doesn't allow 'as' in table aliasing.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Do you create temporary table with "@tempTable subQ" statement?

Comment: Ah, yes - sorry, I created a variable table and populated it with my sample data for writing this query.  You'd want to replace "@tempTable" with whatever your actual table name is.

Comment: Weird, system returns a "FROM keyword not found where expected" problem. Not sure but still have problem with your statement.

Comment: You might have to remove 'as' in the query.  I wrote it in SQL-Server, but after doing some googling, Oracle SQL doesn't allow the 'AS' in table aliasing.

Comment: Still having problem putting it through. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain Oracle allows you to use `CROSS APPLY` these days.

```
SELECT [Worker ID], yt.Time - ca.Time
FROM YourTable yt
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(Time) AS Time
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE [Worker ID] = yt.[Worker ID] AND Time < yt.Time AND InOut = 'In') ca
WHERE yt.InOut = 'Out'
```

Comment: Yea but Oracle doesnt allow DATEDIFF, yet when I changed it to ca.Time-yt.Time I still get missing keyword, dunno why.

Comment: @Zimmon I made a mistake, you can't use TOP in ORACLE. Try it now.

Comment: Still missing keyword. So tired because of this, trying this for 2 days and still I can do it.

Comment: Stupid question but I have to be sure, the [Worker ID] is a column name?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming Worker ID was the name of your column per the table you provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something similar to

```
select sum( time1 - prev_time1 ) from ( 
    select InOut, time1, 
  prev(time1) over (partition by worker_id order by time1) prev_time1, 
  prev(InOut) over (partition by worker_id order by time1) prev_inOut
from MyTABLE
where TimeColumn between trunc(:date1) and trunc( :date1 + 1 )
and workerId = :workerId
) t1
where InOut = 'Out' and prev_InOut = 'In'
```

would go. 
:workerId and :date1 are variables to constrain to one date and one worker as required.